# Negative sign of collector current (Ic-Veb characteristic curve) of pnp BJT on LTspice

Tags: bjt, ltspice

[image]

In the exact same circuitry with a npn transistor i get the same curve but with positive sign. I didnt expect the Ic to turn out negative since on Sedra-Smiths book its also positive.
Shouldn't it be positive?

Comment: Let's think about this... For what purposes would you want to use a PNP in lieu of an NPN?

Comment: Thus far i have only been tough that npn's are preferable to pnp's cause in practice they work better.

Comment: If I remember correctly any current flowing out of the pin is a negative current in Ltspice.

Comment: That's... a bold statement... True, we use NPNs more often than PNPs but we have reasons why we want to use a PNP instead of an NPN... I'll give you a hint, it has to do with current flowing from the emitter to the collector instead of vice versa with an NPN.

Comment: So LTspice registers it as negative because it the opposite of the npn?

Comment: @G36 what do you mean out of the pin? whats the pin? (Not native speaker, so not fluent with the terms)

Comment: "pin" = "contact" or "terminal" or "pad" or ...

Comment: Leaving the collector. In NPN transistor emitter current in LTspice will also be negative because the emitter current leaving the BJT terminal.

Comment: @G36 I see, thanks, thats indeed the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a PNP transistor, conventional current flows out of the collector so Spice might show negative current to indicate direction.

With NPN, current will flow into the collector. Remember all polarities are reversed between NPN and PNP transistors.

It may be easier to understand if you keep your voltage sources in the same place and flip your transistors upside down depending on polarity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

When you plot the currents, make sure you notice which way the icon is pointing when you hover it over the pin of the device for the current you are plotting. The way the current points is arbitrary and so attention is needed to make sure the understanding of the current is aligned with the direction of the simulation.

If it isn't in the direction you would like it, add a negative sign in front of the current by right clicking on the current above the graph and editing the equation.